# NSMutableDictionary won't save data

Tags: objective-c, ios

hope someone can help me with a problem I've been wrestling with...

Using MapBox to develop a map-based app, and I want to attach an NSMutableDictionary to each of the map annotations to store additional data. I had it working but XCode kept throwing me warning about some of my data/object types, so I went through and tidied those up, and now it's broken. The idea is that on ViewDidLoad, the program runs through a set of plist dictionaries to set up each annotation correctly - that's still running okay, because my initial anno markers pop up with their correct settings. However rather than run back to the plist every time, I want to attach a dictionary to each annotation's userinfo property, which I can then use for toggling selection data and other functions. Here's my code:

```
NSDictionary *ExploreSteps = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ExploreSteps" ofType:@"plist"]];
for (NSString *key in [ExploreSteps allKeys])
    {
        //Loop through keys for each anno
        NSDictionary *thisStep = [ExploreSteps objectForKey:key];
        NSNumber *annoIndex = [thisStep objectForKey:@"Index"];
        NSNumber *isLive = [thisStep valueForKey:@"isLive"];
        NSString *annoTitle = [thisStep objectForKey:@"Title"];
        NSString *annoText = [thisStep objectForKey:@"Text"];
        NSString *imagefile = [thisStep objectForKey:@"Imagefile"];
        double longitude = [[thisStep objectForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue];
        double latitude = [[thisStep objectForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue];
        NSString *pagefile = [thisStep objectForKey:@"Pagefile"];
        NSString *audiofile = [thisStep objectForKey:@"Audiofile"];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D annoCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

        RMAnnotation *annotation = [[RMAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:mapView coordinate:annoCoord andTitle:annoTitle];
        annotation.annotationIcon = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imagefile ofType:@"png"]]; 
        annotation.userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:annoIndex, @"index", isLive, @"isLive", annoTitle, @"annoTitle", annoText, @"annoText", imagefile, @"imagefile", pagefile, @"pagefile", audiofile, @"audiofile", nil];
        NSLog(@"Title: %@",[annotation.userInfo objectForKey:@"annoTitle"]);
        [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    }
```

The NSLog should spit out the annoTitle string, but instead it's giving me a null every time, and the behaviour of the rest of the app also shows that info stored in the dictionary simply isn't "getting through".

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

ETA: Modified code for initializing the dictionary (not that it seems to make any difference to the problem!):

```
NSMutableDictionary *myUserInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:annoIndex, @"index", isLive, @"isLive", annoTitle, @"annoTitle", annoText, @"annoText", imagefile, @"imagefile", pagefile, @"pagefile", audiofile, @"audiofile", nil];
        annotation.userInfo = myUserInfo;
        NSLog(@"Title: %@",[annotation.userInfo objectForKey:@"annoTitle"]);
        NSLog(@"Length: %u",[[annotation.userInfo allKeys] count]);
```

(Title now returns "(null)", while Length returns "1", if that's at all helpful...)

Comment: Does annoTitle have proper text after loading it from plist? i.e. after NSString *annoTitle = [thisStep objectForKey:@"Title"] ?

Comment: Maybe you meant NSLog(@"Title: %@",[annotation.userInfo objectForKey:@"Title"]) ?

Comment: Good idea to check - but I stuck an NSLog in to check annoTitle and that's printing the correct info, so yes, it's coming through from the plist...

Comment: Thanks Ramy, but no - @"annoTitle" is correct since that's the key I've set up in the userinfo dictionary. I should add that the same problem is happening with all the other objects, both NSStrings and NSNumbers, that should be storing in the dictionary...

Comment: Did you log annotation to see that it's not nil? Also how is the property userInfo declared?

Comment: I'm using MapBox, so RMAnnotation is part of the framework, as is its userInfo property. Forgive me for being a newb but I'm not sure how I'd log annotation in this case. However, I can tell that they're not nil because I have two test annotations popping up on my map with the coordinates and imagefiles defined in the initial plist...

Comment: Try logging annotation.userInfo right above the line where you're defining it (annotation.userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys....). Maybe you're overwriting a dictionary that already exists?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - tried that, but still no joy - NSLog gives me the same "Null" result there, and a test of the key count confirms that the dictionary doesn't exist till I create it...

Comment: Try logging annotation.userInfo right after you define it this time to see whether the whole dictionary is nil or not.

Comment: As I said, I'm not sure how to log the userinfo object itself, since it's a repository for arbitrary data. However, logging [[annotation.userinfo allKeys] count] returns "1", which presumably means the dictionary *is* getting created. By the way, I've appended the latest version of my code to the original question...

Comment: You log it like any other dictionary: NSLog(@"%@",annotation.userInfo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly one of your objects is `nil`. You mention that `allKeys] count]` returns `1` so I can go further and say that your value for `isLive` is `nil`. Hence your original line:

```
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:annoIndex, @"index", isLive, @"isLive", annoTitle, @"annoTitle", annoText, @"annoText", imagefile, @"imagefile", pagefile, @"pagefile", audiofile, @"audiofile", nil];
```

Acts exactly the same as:

```
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:annoIndex, @"index", nil, @"isLive", annoTitle, @"annoTitle", annoText, @"annoText", imagefile, @"imagefile", pagefile, @"pagefile", audiofile, @"audiofile", nil];
```

And the dictionary takes `annoIndex` to be the final key-value pair.

I'd suggest that probably you want to take a mutable copy of `thisStep` and strip out the keys you don't want, then pass it along as the `userInfo`.

Comment: That's got it - Thanks very much! Turned out the changes I'd made to avoid ARC's "implicit conversion" warnings had ended up affecting the "isLive" item in the plist so it wasn't being read correctly, and as you said, the 'nil' that generated was tripping the dictionary to end prematurely...

Comment: ETA: Thanks also for your comment on the correct dictionary creation procedure above - have reverted to my previous version. Still got a lot to learn...

Answer (score 0):

It's the way you are creating the NSMutableDictionary for userInfo. Take a look at this [Difference between [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:...] and [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:...]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114713/difference-between-nsmutabledictionary-alloc-initwithobjects-and-nsmuta)

"
+dictionaryWithObjects: returns an autoreleased dictionary
-initWithObjects: you must release yourself

if you want the dictionary to persist as a instance variable, you should create it with an init method or retain an autoreleased version, either way you should be sure to release it in your dealloc method
"

Comment: Sorry - useful advice and I've changed over to the Init method, but it's still not making the values "stick"!

Comment: He doesn't want it to persist as an instance variable though. The original form is correct; the person creating the dictionary hands it off to `RMAnnotation` and that's the end of local responsibility. So the `dictionaryWithObjects:...` form was more correct. That said, under ARC it won't make any noticeable difference.